# Returning marshalling errors from a Jersey service

Tags: java, jersey

I have a Jersey service that's accepting an object as XML via a POST method. There are some errors being raised during the marshalling due to invalid data as expected (fields too long, etc). How can I capture and return these errors gracefully instead of getting the generic "The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect" error.

**Clarification:** The bodies of the REST calls are like this:

```
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
@Path("/users")
@POST
public Response createUser(@Context SecurityContext sc, User user) {
    // do some stuff
}
```

Where the user object is sent as the body of the call. The errors are being raised in the sets of the User object.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, first you will need to change the argument of your method to take either a String or a Map. Then you can control the marshaling something like so:

```
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
@Path("/users")
@POST
public Response createUser(@Context SecurityContext sc, String json ) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    User user = mapper.readValue( json, User.class );
```

Then you can put a try..catch around this to catch the validation errors. As for returning this to the client I like to create a Response of BAD_REQUEST and then create an object for the entity of the request. I create one that looks very much like a ConstrainViolationExcpetion. It basically has a one-line message description then a collection of Objects that have fields for "field" and "detail". Then I let it be returned as JSON or XML to the client. Here's an example output in JSON:

```
{"description":"Validation Failed",
 "errors":[
    {"field":"emailAddress","message":"not a well-formed email address"}
    {"field":"phoneNumber","message":"The phone number supplied was null."},
    {"field":"password","message":"may not be null"}]}
```

Here's a quick and dirty example that return a reponse entity based on a basic ConstrainViolationException but I think you can see how to easily add "field" and "message" elements to instances of this class.

```
public class RestValidationErrorEntity {

    public static Response createResponseOrThrow( ConstraintViolationException e ) {
        return Response
            .status( Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST )
            .entity( new RestValidationErrorEntity( e ) )
            .build();
    }

    public String description = "Validation Failed";
    public List<Detail> errors = new ArrayList<>();

    public RestValidationErrorEntity( ConstraintViolationException e ) {
        for ( ConstraintViolation<?> violation : e.getConstraintViolations() ) {
            errors.add(
                new Detail(
                    violation.getPropertyPath().toString(), violation.getMessage()
                ) );
        }
    }

    public static class Detail {
        public String field;
        public String message;

        Detail( String field, String message ) {
            this.message = message;
            this.field = field;
        }
    }
}
```